# POST request is in-appropriate

Tags: python, post, response

I am trying to write a Python script which will download subtitles for movies placed in a specific folder on my PC. I am trying to use Opensubtitle's API ([OpenSubtitle API Docs](https://opensubtitles.stoplight.io/docs/opensubtitles-api/e3750fd63a100-getting-started)) for searching and downloading the subtitles.

```
import os
import requests
import json

# Function to search and download subtitles
def download_subtitles(movie_folder, movie_name):
    # API endpoint and credentials
    url = "https://api.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/subtitles"
    user_agent = "USER_AGENT_NAME"
    token = "API_KEY"

    # Prepare the request headers
    headers = {
        "Api-Key": token,
        "User-Agent": user_agent
    }

    # Prepare the request payload
    payload = {
        "query": movie_name,
        "languages": "eng",  # You can modify the language code as per your preference
        "limit": 1
    }

    # Send the request to the API
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

    # Check the response status
    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            # Parse the response JSON
            data = response.json()
            # Check if subtitles are found
            if data.get("data") and data["data"].get("attributes"):
                subtitle_url = data["data"]["attributes"]["files"][0]["download_link"]
                subtitle_filename = f"{movie_name}.srt"

                # Download the subtitle file
                response = requests.get(subtitle_url)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    # Save the subtitle file inside the movie's folder
                    subtitle_path = os.path.join(movie_folder, subtitle_filename)
                    with open(subtitle_path, "wb") as subtitle_file:
                        subtitle_file.write(response.content)
                    print(f"Subtitle downloaded: {subtitle_filename}")
            else:
                print(f"No subtitles found for: {movie_name}")

        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print(f"Error decoding JSON response for: {movie_name}")
    else:
        print(f"Error occurred while making a request for: {movie_name}")

# Folder path where your movies are located
movies_folder = "C:/Users/abhis/Videos"

# Iterate through each folder in the movies folder
for movie_folder in os.listdir(movies_folder):
    movie_folder_path = os.path.join(movies_folder, movie_folder)
    if os.path.isdir(movie_folder_path):
        # Get the movie name from the folder name
        movie_name = movie_folder

        # Search and download subtitles for the movie
        download_subtitles(movie_folder_path, movie_name)
```

Given above is my code snippet...

I am getting the following error for this:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

I replaced my `USER_AGENT_NAME and` API_KEY` with the actual values but I guess there is some issue in the headers or the URL itself. Can anyone help me to debug this please? I have provided the required documentation above.

Comment: Hard to tell without the ability to test it, as I don't have those APIs, but if you can access the page normally in browser, try adding user agents to your script. 
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Why POST rather than GET?

Comment: @Naruto Here is the api key's and the user name: user_agent = "abhiAppUser"
    token = "bVXzwTMnRn5omtQM9BguFcBxrjTqN7Kw" . Since these key's are freely available, I could just generate another one......